# [Highcharts]: TickInterval on X-Axis is not respected after chart.update();

Tags: highcharts

I'm having an issue with Highcharts where the tickInterval is not respected after initial rendering. I can input data and set the tickInterval to 'Monthly', Highcharts will check and see that there is not enough space for this, so reduces this 'Monthly' to skip a month and give each tick on the x-axis more space to breathe.

However, when you update the charts via `chart.update({}, true)` (where it triggers redraw) **OR** you resize the window a pixel, it will all of a sudden throw away the fact that it skipped a month in between to reserve space and just adds the skipped months in anyway.

I've reproduced the issue in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/StevenSerrien/qp4agz2b/19/show

We are having issue's with this, because we built functionality on top of the rendered labels.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A chart can look slightly different after subsequent rendering and this is known issue in Highcharts.

Please check the explanation from this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14340#issuecomment-708338622

You can use `step` or `tickPositioner` to restrict the way of rendering labels.

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step